# Transform rotate a path inside a SVG

Tags: svg, rotation, css-animations, css-transforms

While `svg` is moving I need the `#winga` to be rotated (left and right) around the top center origin. But I cannot rotate it in any direction.

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 25px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  animation: a01 9s;
  background: #0099cc;
}

@keyframes a01 {
  from {}
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}

#winga {
  fill: gold;
  transform-origin: top center;
  animation: awinga 25s;
}

@keyframes awinga {
  from {};
  to {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
  <path id='winga' d="M100 0 L150 0 L150 300 L100 300 Z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has `;` after `from` in `keyframes`. After rewriting code I found and remove it and it should be working now.

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 25px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  animation: a01 9s;
  background: #0099cc;
}

@keyframes a01 {
  from {}
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}

#winga {
  fill: gold;
  transform-origin: top center;
  animation: awinga 25s;
}

@keyframes awinga {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
  <path id='winga' d="M100 0 L150 0 L150 300 L100 300 Z" />
</svg>
```